# вывести часы на главной форме

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Имеется следующая форма
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как вывести часы в нижнем левом углу?
Код класса-контроллера:

```
 @FXML
public void time () throws InterruptedException {
    //Выводит текущее время на экран
    while(true){
        try {
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formatForTimeNow = new SimpleDateFormat("E hh:mm:ss");
            dateLabel.setText(formatForTimeNow.format(date));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: И в чем, собственно, проблема? Единственное что - надо этот while в другом треде запускать, чтобы визуальная часть не висела в бесконечном цикле

Comment: Попробуешь пояснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо обернуть внутренности метода в отдельный поток и там его запускать. Выглядеть будет примерно так

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Date date = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat formatForTimeNow = new SimpleDateFormat("E hh:mm:ss");
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dateLabel.setText(formatForTimeNow.format(date));
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```